# Qual o sentido de usar dupla negação em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Recentemente, enquanto estudava alguns códigos em JavaScript, me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
```

Sei que:

```
!true == false
!false == true
```

E, consequentemente:

```
!!true == true
!!false == false
```

Então fiquei na dúvida: qual a lógica de se fazer esse tipo de operação?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Essa é uma maneira rápida de converter o resultado de uma expressão para um valor booleano `True`/`False` (ou em termos técnicos, oferecendo garantia de *typecast* para `boolean`), simplificando assim processos de avaliação condicional.

[Existe um post no Stack Overflow original que descreve perfeitamente este comportamento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick). A tradução da parte relevante vem a seguir:

> O primeiro sinal `!` avalia a expressão, convertendo o valor lógico e
>   negando-o.
>   O segundo sinal `!` inverte o valor do primeiro.
>
> Na documentação, a respeito do [operador lógico NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):
>
> > Retorna `false` caso seu operador único pode ser convertido para `true`; caso contrário, retorna `true`.
>
> Os seguintes valores são avaliados como "falso":
>
> - `false`
> - `NaN`
> - `undefined`
> - `null`
> - `""` (empty string)
> - `0`

Comment: Isso é ES5 ou ES6 ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza se não me engano esse typecast é válido desde 1997 (ECMAScript 1a edição).

Comment: https://udgwebdev.com/15-javascript-hacks/ veja esse site. Legal, eu sou newbie em JS. Estou estudando para fazer aplicações usando o Mean.

Answer (score 36):

Como o objetivo do `return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);` é descobrir se o dispositivo atual é um iPad ou não, é interessante/elegante que o retorno da função seja booleano (`true` ou `false`).

O problema é que ao simplesmente chamar a função `navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);` (sem a dupla negação), o retorno será `null` ou `['iPad']` (ou talvez alguma outra coisa), em vez de `true` ou `false`.

Usar o `!!` é uma forma de forçar que o retorno desse `match` seja convertido para um valor booleano, mantendo o valor lógico correto para o objetivo em questão. Em outras palavras, `['iPad']` vira `true` e `null` vira `false`. =)

Em etapas fica mais claro:

1. `navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i); // ex: retorno ['iPad']`
2. `!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i); // primeira negação, !['iPad'] == false`
3. `!!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i); // segunda conversão, !false == true`

Comment: Detalhe: neste caso, seria possível usar `/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)` e a conversão não seria necessária.

Answer (score 12):

A dupla negação serve para tornar a o retorno da função mais typesafe. É uma boa técnica para garantir que determinadas funções só devolvam valores booleanos, abstraindo assim o utilizador da função de retornos que podem não fazer sentido.

Por exemplo

```
function isIpad() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
}

if ( isIpad() ) { ... }
```

Este código vai funcionar porque se for iPad um array é devolvido (e isso é `true`) se não for vai devolver `null` (que é avaliado como `false`). Mas para o developer ver no output de `isIpad()` `null` ou `["iPad"]` foge à semantica do "is" logo a dupla negação força a que a função isIpad() devolva exclusivamente ou `false` ou `true`