# Checar se está vazio independente do tipo, javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma função que verifique se tem algo em branco, vazio, undefined, null etc..

Porém minha dificuldade é que eu não conheço todas as formas que existem de uma string estar "em branco"

eu criei essa função

```
function empty() {
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

    args.forEach(function(argument) {
        if(!argument || 0 === argument.length || !argument || /^\s*$/.test(argument) || argument.length === 0 || !argument.trim()) {
            return false;
        } 
    });
}
```

a intenção é retornar `false` para que eu possa simplesmente verificar se entre minhas variáveis tem alguma em branco dessa forma `if(!empty(var1, var2...)) {`

Porém são várias formas, como eu disse, por exemplo em minhas dúvidas:

Se for uma array, como saber se ela está vazia?

Se for um JSON como saber se está vazio?

Se for apenas números tem como saber se está vazio?

são tantas formas que tem que verificar que eu me perco..

Quando eu digo vazio eu me refiro a undefined, null, preenchido apenas com espaços vazios etc..

Comment: O numero zero deve validar verdadeiro ou falso? que tipos de valores tens?

Comment: @Sergio o número em sí deve se referir a falso, se ele estiver em uma string verdadeiro..

Answer (score 3):

Não existe um valor "vazio" para números e booleanos, a não ser que você defina algum. Este valor "vazio", nestes casos, seria `null`, ou `undefined`.

Estou assumindo que:

- `null` é vazio;
- `undefined` é vazio;
- objetos sem campos é vazio (inclusive herdados);
- arrays sem elementos é vazio;
- strings de tamanho 0 são vazias;
- strings formadas apenas por caracteres em branco são vazias;
- não há um valor específico numérico ou booleano para representar vazio (poderia ser `0` ou `false`, talvez).

Assim, ela poderia ser escrita da seguinte forma:

```
function empty() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return args.some(function(argument) {
        return argument === null
            || typeof argument === "undefined"
            || (Array.isArray(argument) && argument.length === 0)
            || (typeof argument === "object" && emptyObject(argument))
            || (typeof argument === "string" && (argument.length === 0 || argument.trim().length === 0));
    });
}

function emptyObject(arg) {
    var count = 0;
    for ( var i in arg ) {
        count++;
        break;
    }
    return count === 0;
}
```

O método `emptyObject` checa quantos campos um objeto possui. Não conheço outra maneira de fazer isso.

A chamada ao método `Array.some` serve para que quando um único item vazio seja encontrado, o método já retorne, não verificando todos os demais itens.

**Não** *testei, então podem haver alguns erros ;D*

*Melhorias são bem vindas!*

Comment: Consegui ter um rumo agora!! Obrigada!, mas tenho umas dúvidas, o que quiz dizer com herdados? Irei testar a fundo a função e lhe respondo..

Comment: O objeto sendo verificado se esta vazio no método `emptyObject` pode ser herdado de outro objeto (POO). Neste caso, estes campos serão considerados pelo método.  Ok, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Em Javascript, a maneira mais rápida de validar o resultado de uma expressão incluindo os tipos mais utilizados de valores que representam um *não-valor* é a **dupla negação**. [Mais detalhes nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29016/1897).

Os possíveis valores que podem sofrer *typecast* para verdadeiro/falso são:

- `false`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `""` (string vazia)
- `0`

Alguns exemplos de validação via dupla negação (tirados [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597474/1845714)):

```
          !!false === false
           !!true === true

              !!0 === false
!!parseInt("foo") === false // NaN
              !!1 === true
             !!-1 === true  // -1 é verdadeiro

             !!"" === false // string vazia é 'falsa'
          !!"foo" === true  // string não-vazia é 'verdadeira'
        !!"false" === true  // ...mesmo se conter o valor "false"

     !!window.foo === false // undefined é falso
           !!null === false // null também

             !!{} === true  // um objeto vazio é 'verdadeiro';
             !![] === true  // um array vazio também.
```