# If null, NaN, false e undefined em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quero saber como fazer um `if` para verificar qualquer um desses possíveis estados.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que queres fazer?

Comment: Essa resposta [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in) te atenderia? Postei uma resposta com ela mais não foi bem recebida. Entendi errado @AllanRamos?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual o sentido de usar dupla negação em Javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como o JavaScript é dinâmico, você pode tentar "coagir" a conversão destes valores para `boolean`, isso fará com que todos os itens citados (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `NaN`, `""`), equivalham a `false`.

Se você fizer uma comparação de um dos valores com `== false`, a resposta será `true`, porém, se utilizar `===` a resposta será `false`. Isso ocorre porque o `==` desconsidera os tipos e tenta forçar a conversão para validar os valores.

O `if` e o operador de negação (**`!`**) têm o mesmo comportamento de **`==`**.

#### Exemplo com `if`:

```js
var v1 = null;
var v2 = undefined;
var v3 = NaN;
var v4 = 0;
var v5 = false; // Não precisava dessa, né? :p
var v6 = "";

valida(v1);
valida(v2);
valida(v3);
valida(v4);
valida(v5);
valida(v6);

function valida(variavel){
  if(variavel)
    console.log("true");
  else
    console.log("false");
}
```

#### Exemplo com `===`

<sup>Não vou fazer com todos os valores pra não ficar muito longo.</sup>

```js
var v1 = "";

valida(v1);

function valida(variavel){
  if(variavel == false)
    console.log("true");
  else
    console.log("false");
  
  if(variavel === false)
    console.log("true");
  else
    console.log("false");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Normalmente se usa um simples if(variavel) para determinar qualquer das situações em código, mas para detectar individualmente cada situação, segue um resumo:

## Testando se é `null`:

```
if( minhaVariavel === null ) ...
```

se testar só com `==` equivale a `undefined`

## Testando se é `NaN`:

```
if( isNaN( minhaVariavel ) ) ...
```

ou

```
minhaVariavel !== minhaVariavel
```

## Testando se é `false`

```
if( minhaVariavel === false ) ...
```

## Testando se é `undefined`:

Para uso geral:

```
if( typeof minhaVariavel == 'undefined' )
```

caso queira testar se o valor de uma variável existente é indefinido:

```
if( minhaVariavel === undefined ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz:

```
 var x = false;

 if(x === false || x === undefined || isNaN(x)) {

 }
```

Qualquer dúvida, olha esses links: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: SIIIIIM, vou corrigir!! Obrigado pela observação kkk

Answer (score 1):

## Explicação

Assim como informado no vídeo de Rodrigo Branas ([aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP2ProYre4k)), o Javascript identifica como **false** alguns casos, sendo eles:

- 0;
- NaN;
- ""(string vazia);
- false;
- null;
- undefined.

Ou seja, se eu quisesse apenas verificar se uma variável contém um valor, sem ter medo dela estar *null* ou *undefined*, eu deveria apenas fazer:

```
if(variavel) {
  //Seu código
}
```

## Extra

Para testar isso que falei, segue trecho de código:

```
var a = 0;
var b = false;
var c = "";
var d = "abc" * 2;
var e = null;
var f;

if(!a) {
  alert("A false");
}

if(!b) {
  alert("B false");
}

if(!c) {
  alert("C false");
}

if(!d) {
  alert("D false");
}

if(!e) {
  alert("E false");
}

if(!f) {
  alert("F false");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( ! variavel ) {
    console.log("Variável inválida");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, utilize typeof para verificar undefined.
Por exemplo:

```js
var variavel; 

if (typeof variavel === "undefined"){
  console.log("sem valor atribuido");
}
```