# O uso do ponto de exclamação triplo (!!!)

Tags: javascript, lógica

Considere o seguinte código:

```
if (!!!window.customElements) {
    execPolyfill();          
}
```

Qual a função dos 3 pontos de exclamação antes da expressão `window.customElements` sendo que apenas 1 teria o mesmo efeito?

Comment: Tripla negação nega de modo negado!!!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu percebi mas qual a razão de utilizar isso, não bastava utilziar apenas 1?

Comment: Só consigo pensar que a intenção é melhorar a legibilidade.

Comment: É legibilidade, veja esta [pergunta relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154510/the-use-of-the-triple-exclamation-mark). O valor irá ser sempre o mesmo que `!window.customElements`

Comment: @Isac era legal colocar essa respota do SOen aqui em português.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes concordo com você. Não sei se quem fez o código ouviu falar "para pegar o valor booleano de um _falsy_ em javascript, use a dupla negação" e aplicou esse princípio para pegar o inverso, daí a tripla. Temos duas classes de operadores de negação envolvidos aqui: _falsy_ => booleano e booleano ==> booleano. As duas negações mais à esquerda (portanto, as últimas a serem operadas) são do segundo tipo, já apenas a primeira negação (colada ao resultado da chamada de função) faz o trabalho de pegar um _falsy_ e transformar num booleano. Como negar negar um booleano é idempotente...

Comment: A pergunta está [relacionada com essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-negação-em-javascript) mas é ligeiramente diferente, por isso não concordo em ser marcada como [duplicada].

Comment: Não há diferença entre `!a` e `!!!a` -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318045/6510304