# Validar campos de um select pelo jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário usando o step wizard conforme o link abaixo:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/j6rkb

Ele funciona corretamente, porém vi que a validação de campos só funciona para campos **input**. Como eu poderia fazer para validar também campos combobox? Vejam abaixo o jquery dele:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
        allWells = $('.setup-content'),
        allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $item = $(this);

        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            $item.addClass('btn-success');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
            $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
        }
    });

    allNextBtn.click(function () {
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
            curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
            isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
            if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
                isValid = false;
                $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            }
        }

        if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
    });

    $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-success').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

O select seria esse:

```
<select name="Estado" class="form-control" required="required">
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
   <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
</select>
```

O código completo encontra-se no link que passei acima, pois estou copiando fielmente conforme desenvolvido pelo autor.

Comment: Quando você fala combobox está se referindo a um select né?

Comment: Olá João, isso... é um select simples do Bootstrap.

Comment: Corrigi o título com meu post ;)

Comment: Show, não havia entendido a parte do combobox.

Comment: Acredito que seria legal se colocasse o select do html para facilitar o entendimento da pergunta.

Comment: Certo. Coloquei o código do select no post.

Comment: A partir do momento que você constrói um select, presume-se que as opções são válidas, portanto validar opção que se oferece em select acho desnecessário, ou será que estou enganado?

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta correta seria `verificar se foi selecionado alguma opção em um select`

Comment: Fox, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Comment: Olá João. Feito ;) Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar os campos de um `select` você tem duas opções (que eu conheço).

A primeira delas é utilizando um `required` dentro da tag do `select` (o que você já está fazendo).

```html
<form id="form">
  <select name="Estado" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Lembrando que o `required` não é suportado pelo Safari (os outros é normal, só o Edge e o IE que é somente a partir da versão 10).

Caso queira fazer algo mais personalizado você poderá fazer de outra maneira. Veja o exemplo:

```js
$('#estado').on('change', function(){
    $('#resultado').text(!!this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <select name="Estado" class="form-control" id="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  </select>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

A partir disso você poderia fazer uma personalização no estilo do formulário que está implementando. Veja:

```js
$('#estado').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == false) {
    this.classList.add('error');
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('error');
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 2px solid #a94442;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <select name="Estado" class="form-control" id="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  </select>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

Lembrando que nos exemplos eu usei um pouco de JavaScript "puro" e em partes com jQuery. Mas, você poderia fazer tudo somente com jQuery, mudariam poucas coisas.

Comment: Pode explicar esses 2 pontos de exclamação

Comment: Veja essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) aqui do SO que explica bem certo o que o !! faz.

Comment: achei em SOpt https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript

Answer (score 0):

[**Form validation with jQuery**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#meuForm").validate({
            rules: {
                Estado: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
    Estado: "Selecione uma opção"
    
  },        
     submitHandler: function (form) { // para demo
                console.log('validado');
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="meuForm">
  <select name="Estado" class="form-control" required="required">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Validar"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos!