# O que é esse operador !! em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores

Estava analisando um código em PHP e me deparei com o seguinte:

```php
$result = !! $row;

return $result;
```

O que é esse `!!` e o que ele faz?

Comment: Converte o resultado em boolean.

Comment: @rray então o `(bool)$row` e `!! $row` é a mesma coisa?

Comment: Não tá fácil achar mais é dup.

Comment: Exato, lembro que tinha uma sobre C que explicava isso

Comment: @Maniero https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript esta?

Comment: @Maniero eu procurei bastante no site mas não encontrei nada, portanto perguntei. Mas se tiver uma pergunta que já responde isso, pode sinalizar minha Q como dup.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu acho que é.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

se usa 2 `!!` para converter para binário `Type-safe`, ou seja se o método ou função que for usar esse valor fizer um `gettype` o resultado será boolean. Nem toda API ou lib confia na tipagem dinâmica talvez esse seja o caso do uso.

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
>
> the integers 0 and -0 (zero)
>
> the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"
>
> an array with zero elements
>
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

e no caso `(bool)$row` e `!!$row` geram o mesmo resultado `bool(true|false)`.

@from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 14):

Complementando a resposta do Jroger, e aplicando no contexto do código da pergunta, o uso duplo do operador de negação `!!` pode ser utilizado para descobrir se um array é vazio ou não, como substituto para `count($array) > 0` ou `!(empty($array))`.

```
<?php
  $a = !![];   // retorna false;

  echo ($a ? 'array cheia' : 'array vazia'). PHP_EOL; // retorna 'array vazia'

  $array = ["um", "dois", "três"];

  echo (!!$array ? 'array cheia' : 'array vazia') . PHP_EOL; // retorna 'array cheia'
?>
```

Pode também poderia ser utilizado com string, **mas não é aconselhável pois a string "0" dá falso resultado para vazio**:

```php
<?php

  echo (!!'testing' ? 'string cheia' : 'string vazia') . PHP_EOL; // retorna 'string cheia'

  echo (!!'' ? 'string cheia' : 'string vazia') . PHP_EOL;        // retorna 'string vazia'

  echo (!!'0' ? 'string cheia' : 'string vazia') . PHP_EOL;       // retorna falso resultado 'string vazia'

?>
```

Comment: Resposta muito boa.