# Como verificar se um array contém um determinado elemento

Tags: javascript, array, indexof

Tentei com o `indexOf` (é um requisito da questão utilizar), mas estou tendo muita dificuldade. O código que eu estou tentando utilizar faz o contrário:

```
function contem(elemento){
let array =[];
  for(var i=0; i< elemento.length; i++)
   array = elemento.indexOf(i);
      if(array!= -1){
        return true;
      }}
```

Comment: Use método Array.includes() que retorna true ou false.

Comment: também usaria o `includes`. `const list = [1, 2, 3]` `list.includes(2)`retornaria true, por exemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Verificar a existência de um tipo primitivo

Se você quiser verificar a existência de um tipo [primitivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Tipos_de_Dados), pode utilizar o [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ou [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains):

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(list.indexOf(9)); // -1
console.log(list.indexOf(4)); // 3

console.log(list.includes(8)); // false
console.log(list.includes(3)); // true
```

Conforme você pode ter percebido acima, os dois métodos são bem similares, mas:

- `indexOf` retorna o índice do elemento que você passou como argumento. Caso o elemento não exista, `-1` será retornado;
- `includes` retorna um booleano verdadeiro se o elemento passado existir no array. Caso contrário, um booleano falso retornar-se-á.

Então, já que é requisito da pergunta utilizar `indexOf`, podemos criar uma função `contain`:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function contain(arr, val) {
  // Vale lembrar que o método `indexOf` retorna o índice do valor
  // caso for encontrado e `-1` caso não for encontrado. Logo, uma das
  // formas de converter o valor para booleano é fazer a comparação
  // conforme abaixo.
  // Se o índice retornado for DIFERENTE de `-1`, `true` será retornado.
  // Caso contrário (o valor não existe, logo, `-1` foi retornado),
  // a comparação abaixo resultará em `false`.
  return arr.indexOf(val) !== -1;
}

console.log(contain(list, 2)); // true
console.log(contain(list, 9)); // false
```

Portanto, se você quiser verificar a existência de um tipo primitivo do array, não há a necessidade de usar nenhum laço de repetição, como o `for`.

---

### Verificar a existência de um objeto

No entanto, se você estiver trabalhando com um array de [objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Objetos), deverá utilizar um laço de repetição, como o `for`. Apesar disso, nesse caso, o `indexOf` não é necessário e não deve ser utilizado.

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }
];

function contain(arr, key, val) {
  // Iteramos sobre cada elemento do array:
  for (const obj of arr) {
    // Se existir um objeto com a chave passada (`key`),
    // e for igual ao valor esperado (`val`), retornamos
    // `true`. Caso contrário, passa-se à próxima iteração: 
    if (obj[key] === val) return true;
  }
  
  // Se chegamos até aqui, quer dizer que nenhum objeto da
  // lista satisfaz as nossas condições. Portanto, retornamos `false`.
  return false;
}

console.log(contain(list, 'id', 2)); // true
console.log(contain(list, 'id', 9)); // false
```

No entanto, ao invés de criar esse código enorme para fazer isso, você pode fazer uso do [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), que retorna o valor da lista desde que satisfaça uma condição. Note que se nenhum valor satisfazer as condições, `undefined` será retornado.

Portanto, ao [utilizando um operador de negação (NOT) duas vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-javascript) conseguimos converter o retorno do método `find` em um booleano.

Veja como fica mais simples:

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }
]

function contain(arr, key, val) {
  // O método `find` retorna o elemento encontrado. Portanto,
  // utilizamos dois operadores de negação (NOT) para transformar
  // o objeto em um booleano (`true` ou `false`).
  return !!arr.find((obj) => obj[key] === val);
}

console.log(contain(list, 'id', 2)); // true
console.log(contain(list, 'id', 9)); // false
```

Comment: Eu não estava sabendo utilizar o .indexOf(), mas com a tua explicação ficou bem mais claro. No caso, o indexOf() sempre vai ter dois parametros na sintaxe? voce sabe algum material que foque em uma explicaçao mais simplificada de indexOf?

Comment: Sim, o `indexOf` recebe dois argumentos: o primeiro deles, que é o elemento que você quer buscar o índice e o segundo o ponto de partida da busca. Para saber mais, leia [essa documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Irei ler, vlw!!

Answer (score 0):

//isso vai verificar se o numero contem na MATRIZ de nome ELEMENTO.

```
function contem(elemento,numero){ 
  var aux = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ 
   if (numero === elemento[i]){
     aux = elemento[i];
  } 
  }
  if (aux > 0 ) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function contem (array,valor){
 var aux=0;
  for (var i=0 ;i<array.length;i++){
    return (array.indexOf(valor)!=(-1));
  }
}
```

Comment: function contem (array,valor){
 var aux=0;for (var i=0 ;i<array.length;i++){return (array.indexOf(valor)!=(-1));}}

Answer (score -1):

Testei aqui deu certo.

```
function contem(vetor, elemento){
    for(var i = 0; i < vetor.length ; i++){
        if(vetor.indexOf(elemento) != -1)
            return true;
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 function contem(array,numero){

   let aux = array.indexOf(numero)

   return (aux != -1 == true)


  }
```