# Atribuições de valores em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando meus estudos em JS e estou com a seguinte dúvida. Considerem o código abaixo:

```
const vazio = null
const resultado = vazio || 'Anonimo'

console.log(resultado)
```

O resultado do console será a exibição da string 'Anonimo'.

Eu sei que valores nulos são considerados falsos, mas não entendi o comportamento do JS de atribuir a string 'Anonimo' para a constante resultado. Achei que ele ia converter a string 'Anonimo' para boolean(true) e atribuir para a constante resultado a comparação booleana: false || true = false.

Porque esse comportamento do JS?

Desde já agradeço a atenção

Comment: O || é um operador de lógica e não um meio de "conversão", recomendo que leia [O que são os valores truthy e falsy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/3635) - Recomendo que leia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: Oi Guilherme, obrigado pelo conteúdo, muito esclarecedor... Mas nele não tem um exemplo específico similar ao exemplo que citei e não consegui abstrair com o conteúdo indicado.

Comment: Oi Bruno. O operador || não irá converter em true ou false, o segundo valor após o || é a alternativa ao primeiro valor antes do ||, que não precisa ser exatamente false, ele pode ser "falsy" (são falsy valores como null, undefined, Number -0 ou +0 e NaN), ou seja, não vai "converter", vai tratar dentro do truthy ou falsy, sendo o valor após o || atribuido apenas se o valor antes for falsy... No entanto se fizesse isso `const resultado = !!(vazio || 'Anonimo')` você teria um valor  boolean de resultado, leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29014/3635